# Entity Framework Inheritance - Multiple child instances of same base instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following model:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teacher : Person
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Student : Person
{
    public int NumberOfClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Using that model and Entity Framework, is it possible to have a "Student" instance and a "Teacher" instance both derived from the same base "Person" instance? In other words, can a "Person" be both a "Student" and a "Teacher"?

If so, what would be the best inheritance strategy to use to represent this scenario?

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 What?

Comment: Ok I will provide an answer, but only one the basis that you Google "inheritance in Entity Framework" before I do so.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 I obviously did that before posting this question, but every example I've seen depicts a scenario where the base instance can only be of one of the derived types. Using the model I provided above, a "Person" can only be either a "Student" or a "Teacher".

Comment: I think you might be fundementally misunderstand polymorphism. Neither can "be" a person explicitly, but can be cast as a person. I'll add an example of how to use in my answer.

Comment: @Zeiffelin, can you please provide some more information about how you plan to use this models in you programm to let us understand what are you trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "abstract" keyword is the key to this. Not sure why you were using "partial". You need to select a strategy first - this link explains all. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int NumberOfClasses { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT - example useage **

```
public void GetSomeDetailAboutAPerson(Person person)
{
    return person.SomeSharedDetailFromBaseClass;
}

public void Something()
{
    Teacher teacher = myService.GetTeacherById(3);
    var someDetailOrOther = this.GetSomeDetailAboutAPerson(teacher);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't made myself very clear, so let me try to explain it better. Suppose that I'm using TPT, and therefore have 3 tables (Person, Student and Teacher). What I would like to achieve is to have one record in "Person" referenced by records in both "Student" and "Teacher". Using a real world example, suppose that "John" is a person, and that he's both a student and a teacher. Does EF support such scenario?

Comment: Do I need to explain why your answer is a bad idea? Ok. If you will have a need to add 100 more professions you will have 100 different entities in your DB! THIS IS fundamentally wrong decision!!! Too much poor answer!

Comment: @Maris I think you're totally lost here. I appreciate your effort, but it doesn't seem like you understand what my issue is.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 I'm gonna mark your post as an accepted answer, since you gave the final answer to my question in its comments. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries! Hope you get there. Sounds like a really meaty architecture situation - quite jealous!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible... And a person may be both, a student or a teacher.

What do you exactly mean by "inheritance strategy"??

The way you are doing it, is OK.

Check this :
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: no, i really saw that after posting it... can you please tell me why it was completely wrong??

Comment: Firstly, "A person may be both a student or a teacher" doesn't make any sense. Secondly, you are asking a question, and THEN saying what the person is doing is OK!

Comment: "A person may be both a student or a teacher" was answer of this
"is it possible to have a "Student" instance and a "Teacher" instance both derived from the same base "Person" instance? In other words, can a "Person" be both a "Student" and a "Teacher"?"


Anyways.. thank you..

Comment: A "Person" can't be anything. The object is only ever a "Student" or a "Teacher". The fact that the class inherits FROM "Person" only becomes relevant in an example like I've provided above.